# Error building chaincode written in go

Tags: go, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I try to modify the example described in [this hyperledger example](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html) I get some error when adding [this external library](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/protos/ledger/queryresult) in order to get the History of the chaincode state.
Why does that happen?

I add the library with govendor, but when I run this command:

```
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n $CC_NAME -l "$LANGUAGE" -v 1.0 -c $INIT_STR -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

I get this error:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode:
>   rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 2 "# firstExample
>   chaincode/input/src/firstExample/firstStep.go:104:11: cannot assign *"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/ledger/queryresult".KeyModification to kM (type *"firstExample/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/ledger/queryresult".KeyModification) in multiple assignment
>   chaincode/input/src/firstExample/firstStep.go:146:11: cannot assign *"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/ledger/queryresult".KeyModification to kM (type *"firstExample/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/ledger/queryresult".KeyModification) in multiple assignment
>   chaincode/input/src/firstExample/firstStep.go:156:11: cannot assign *"github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/ledger/queryresult".KeyModification to kM (type *"firstExample/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/ledger/queryresult".KeyModification) in multiple assignment

I have some troubles with this. I'm sure that the library is imported because if I build the chaincode written in go with the command:

```
go build
```

I get no errors.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to guess without seeing actual code which cause the compilation error, while it seems that you are not taking care of the second parameter which returned by `HistoryQueryIteratorInterface#Next()` API or even `ChaincodeStubInterface#GetHistoryForKey()`. Please see example of how to use those APIs correctly:

```
// GetPreviousValue reads previous value of given key
func (pm *personManagement) GetPreviousValue(params []string, stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) peer.Response {
    historyIer, err := stub.GetHistoryForKey(params[0])

    if err != nil {
        errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] cannot retrieve history of key <%s>, due to %s", params[0], err)
        fmt.Println(errMsg)
        return shim.Error(errMsg)
    }

    if historyIer.HasNext() {
        modification, err := historyIer.Next()
        if err != nil {
            errMsg := fmt.Sprintf("[ERROR] cannot read key record modification, key <%s>, due to %s", params[0], err)
            fmt.Println(errMsg)
            return shim.Error(errMsg)
        }
        fmt.Println("Returning information about", string(modification.Value))
        return shim.Success(modification.Value)
    }


    fmt.Printf("No history found for key %s\n", params[0])
    return shim.Success([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("No history for key %s", params[0])))
}
```

**NOTE**: Please pay attention that `historyIer.Next()` returns history value and the error.